# Facebook sdk: login screen appears in popup instead of connecting facebook app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am trying to login into my app with facebook connect. Login UI appears in popup instead of taking me to facebook app.

I have checked my bundle id, app id etc. No luck.

Please help![image: Fb Connect appears in popup]

Comment: Is facebook app installed on your device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add In Your `.plist` file Check below image[image: Add this]
and Comeback Url in `AppDelegate` file

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for xcode 9.2 swift 4.1. Add In Your .plist file.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>facebook</string>
    <string>fbapi</string>        
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>XXXXXXXX</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>XXXXXX</string>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fbXXXXX</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Add this in your AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    return true
}
```